# Reorder columns of a dataframe, on a row by row basis, in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe in R that looks something like this:

```
df <- paste0(c(letters[seq( from = 1, to = 5 )]),":",round(runif(5),2)) 
df <- as.data.frame(t(df))
df2 <- paste0(c(letters[seq( from = 1, to = 5 )]),":",round(runif(5),2)) 
df2 <- as.data.frame(t(df2))
df3 <- paste0(c(letters[seq( from = 1, to = 5 )]),":",round(runif(5),2)) 
df3 <- as.data.frame(t(df3))
df <- rbind(df, setNames(sample(df2), names(df2)))
df <- rbind(df, setNames(sample(df3), names(df3)))

df


      V1     V2     V3     V4     V5
1 a:0.21 b:0.49 c:0.96 d:0.95 e:0.03
2 b:0.33 c:0.25 e:0.81 d:0.94 a:0.02
3 c:0.34 e:0.26 a:0.31 d:0.55 b:0.63
```

The characters before the colon reflects the *type* of measurement and the number after the colon reflect the measurement itself.

I would like to resort each row so that each *type* of measurement (i.e., characters before the colon) is in the same column. It should look like this:

```
      V1     V2     V3     V4     V5
1 a:0.21 b:0.49 c:0.96 d:0.95 e:0.03
2 a:0.02 b:0.33 c:0.25 d:0.94 e:0.81 
3 a:0.31 b:0.63 c:0.34 d:0.55 e:0.26
```

Or better yet:

```
  a    b    c    d      e
1 0.21 0.49 0.96 0.95 0.03
2 0.02 0.33 0.25 0.94 0.81 
3 0.31 0.63 0.34 0.55 0.26
```

Any ideas on how I could reorder each row so that the characters before the colon are the same in a given column?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `substr`.

```
res <- as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(x) x[order(substr(x, 1, 1))])))
res
#       V1     V2     V3     V4     V5
# 1 a:0.96 b:0.94 c:0.34 d:0.85  e:0.2
# 2 a:0.84 b:0.32 c:0.78 d:0.67 e:0.32
# 3 a:0.59 b:0.82 c:0.79  d:0.7  e:0.2
```

Or, to get rid of the suffixes and convert to numeric:

```
res <- as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(x) 
  as.numeric(as.character(substring(x, 3)[order(substr(x, 1, 1))])))))
res
#     V1   V2   V3   V4   V5
# 1 0.96 0.94 0.34 0.85 0.20
# 2 0.84 0.32 0.78 0.67 0.32
# 3 0.59 0.82 0.79 0.70 0.20

str(res)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ V1: num  0.96 0.84 0.59
# $ V2: num  0.94 0.32 0.82
# $ V3: num  0.34 0.78 0.79
# $ V4: num  0.85 0.67 0.7
# $ V5: num  0.2 0.32 0.2
```

Or, using regex:

```
as.data.frame(t(apply(df2, 1, function(x) {
  g1 <- gsub(x, pattern="(\\w+\\:).*", r="\\1")
  g2 <- gsub(x, pattern="\\w+\\:(.*)", r="\\1")
  as.numeric(as.character(g2[order(g1)]))
})))
#     V1   V2   V3   V4   V5
# 1 0.96 0.94 0.34 0.85  0.2
# 2 0.84 0.32 0.78 0.67 0.32
# 3 0.59 0.82 0.79  0.7  0.2
```

---

*Data for df2*

```
df2 <- df
df2[] <- lapply(df2, function(x) as.character(x))
df2[2, ] <- c("cc:0.78", "e:0.32", "dd:0.67", "a:0.84", "bb:0.32")
df2
#        V1     V2      V3     V4      V5
# 1  a:0.96 b:0.94  c:0.34 d:0.85   e:0.2
# 2 cc:0.78 e:0.32 dd:0.67 a:0.84 bb:0.32
# 3   d:0.7 b:0.82   e:0.2 a:0.59  c:0.79
```

Comment: This is great! Is there a way to get substr to select all characters up to the colon, as opposed to defining the start and stop position? In my actual data, there is sometimes more than one character before the colon.

Answer (score 2):

We can get data in long format, get data before colon and after colon into `separate` columns and get data in wide format again.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -row, names_to = 'col') %>%
  separate(value, into = c('col', 'value'), sep = ":", convert = TRUE) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-row)

# A tibble: 3 x 5
#    a     b     c     d     e
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  0.1   0.61  0.53  0.82  0.21
#2  0.62  0.93  0.18  0.39  0.34
#3  0.94  0.95  0.41  0.74  0.9
```

Comment: Very nice. You could make it one line shorter by adding `, names_to="col"` in the `pivot_longer` function, then you don't need to deselect the `name` later. Also, `into=c('name', 'value')` and then the `pivot_wider` would only need to specify the id_cols column (row). The other arguments take the defaults. I know how you like minimal code. :)